# How determine physical state of the speakers

Tags: linux, bash, alsa, headphone-jack

How to determine whether or not the speakers are turned on or off in bash script?

Speakers connected to PC via 3.5 jack.

Comment: You can only detect jack insertion, not power state.

Comment: Speakers are not "turned on or off", they receive an analog signal that can be positive or negative, and is neutral at rest. With Pulseaudio, you can monitor what data is sent to one particular output (e.g. line-out for speakers), and see if it's non-zero by using `sox` or similar for a short bit of data. But you didn't say *why* you need that, so that may not be the solution you want.

Comment: I'm want run shell script when speakers power on. You will not be difficult to give a small example?

Comment: Is your system actually capable of determining this (i.e., does *anything* happend when you switch them on)? It is likely that, as seen from the PC, there is no electrical difference whatsoever.